# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden MVC IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis, windows10

Tengo un problema con mi IIS, formatee mi computadora e instale nuevamente IIS.
Pero al querer entrar a una aplicación MVC me manda el error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya reinstale IIS desde Turn WIndows features on or off varias veces y nada.
También quiere ejecutar el comando aspnet_regiis.exe pero me manda el siguiente mensaje:

```
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).
```

También agregue esta linea en el web.config y nada

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    ...
<system.webServer>
```

Incluso e intentado con el comando y nada

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /all
```

Esta es la configura de mi IIS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor :(

Comment: El problema era al momento de publicar, no estaba borrando los archivos anteriores y por eso mandaba el error.

Answer (score 4):

Debes darle permisos de netnetworks a la carpeta del proyecto , en el aplication pool debes colocar Netservices

adjunto los pasos para habilitar los permisos al proyectos en IIS , cualquier cosa me escribes amigo.

[image: Paso 1]

[image: Paso 2]

[image: Paso 3]

[image: Paso 4]

Comment: Seguro que los futuros usuarios te agradecerian si desarrollas mejor tu respuesta con algunas instruccion de como hacer/habilitar lo que comentas . Un saludo!

Comment: Tienes razon voy a sacar capturas , es que lo solucione esta semana

Comment: Muchas gracias! la comunidad te lo agradece